# Change icon size in Mutiny dock

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, dock, mutiny

With Unity it is possible to change the size of the applications icons shown in the launcher (number of pixels). How can I change the size of the icons show in the Mutiny dock?

Comment: I've also been trying to figure this out. (By "launcher" I assume you mean the vertical bar of application icons on the left hand side of the screen.) It wasn't immediately obvious - you have to right click the launcher to get preferences - but you need to click close to the bottom where you get a different set of options from the middle of the bar.